# How to get the current location of the device? google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, localization, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to know the latitude and longitude of the marker that is placed when I click on my map, and I also need to know how to implement so that when I open the map a marker is placed in the current location, I have seen many videos and tutorials but none works or It's obsolete etc

the relevant code:

**onCreate:**

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    mPost = new Post();
    initPantallaAdd();
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());


    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapAddUbicacion);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please install google play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**onMapReady:**

```
  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


     LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-0.193805, -78.467102);
    CameraPosition cp = CameraPosition.builder().target(sydney).zoom(16).tilt(3).build();

    float zoomlevel = 16;

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp));

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            mMap.clear();
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude)).title("Selected point");
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        }
    });
   }
```

I implemented these methods but I don't know what to do:

```
  //==============================================================================================
// ON CONNECTION CALLBACKS
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

//==============================================================================================
// LOCATION LISTENER

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To work with map you have to follow some steps to configure it.

**1- create a project at google developer console. https://console.developers.google.com/**

**2- select the project and leftmenu will show credential option click on it and than you will get option create credentialclick on it than it will ask for create api key click and create our project api key.**

**3-click on dashboard and select the project on top of the screen here you will get an option for enable api.**

**4- In this you will there is many google api, in the google map api section select  google map api android and click enable .**

now you will get a working api key this api key is used to work with map **here i am giving you my repository you can take example from it. you do not need to configure for api key i am using my api key in it.**
              If you want to use you own api key than only you need to do is update the api key in the project inside manifiest file meta data tag. **[here is a working example](https://github.com/Ashif76/FusionLocationExample)**

Answer (score 0):

GPS service is needed to get current location latitude and longitude.

**Android Location API** will provide the fused location functionality to you. Check the following links for better understanding.

1. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html
2. http://clover.studio/2016/08/09/getting-current-location-in-android-using-location-manager/

Comment: Thanks i will see this

Comment: the first link is incomplete tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code for getting the current latitude and longitude...

```
 public class MerchantTrack extends Common implements 
 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.merchant_track);
    backbuttn=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backbuttn);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    connectClient();



}


protected void connectClient() {
    // Connect the client.
    if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() && mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
        return true;
    } else {
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {
            // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
            UberMapsActivity.ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new UberMapsActivity.ErrorDialogFragment();
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
        }

        return false;
    }
}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS location was found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        latitudE = location.getLatitude();
        longitudE = location.getLongitude();

        Log.d("locationnss", String.valueOf(latitudE));


        new MerchLocAsync().execute();

    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MerchantTrack.this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setMessage("Current location is unavailable!")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
    startLocationUpdates();
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
            mLocationRequest, this);
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent home = new Intent(MerchantTrack.this,Home.class);
    startActivity(home);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: The LocationServices.API, doesnt founds

Comment: Just use this library -     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

Comment: I use the 10.0.2 with firebase, this not cause a exception?